# When does completion preserve injectivity?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $ f:A\to B$ be an injective, local homorphism between two Noetherian local rings. Consider the completions $\hat A$ and $\hat B$  with respect the maximal ideals. We have an induced homomorphism $\hat f: \hat A \to\hat B$. What assumptions do we need in order to ensure that also $\hat f$ is injective?

My main interest is geometric, so for example the local map induced by a surjective morphism between Noetherian schemes.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Trivia: if $f$ is an homeomorphism onto its image (e.g., $A$ and $B$ are DVR), so is $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Uhm, yes I'm interested in the DVR case. But why?

Comment: Assume that $A$ and $B$ are DVRs with uniformizing elements $\pi_A \in A$ and $\pi_B \in B$. Write $f(\pi_A) = u \pi_B^{\nu}$ with $u$ a unit of $B$ and $\nu$ a positive integer. Then $f(A) \cap \pi_B^{n \nu} B \subseteq f(\pi_A^{n}A)$ for every $n \ge 0$, hence $f$ is open.

Comment: The  natural condition is that the topology on $A$ induced by powers of its maximal ideal and the topology induced by the powers of the maximal ideal of $B$ intersected with $A$ are the same.

Comment: Trivia continued: If $\hat{f}$ is injective and if $\hat{A}$ is compact (i.e, the residue field of $A$ is finite), then $f$ is an homeomorphism onto its image. So the "natural condition" is necessary under the compactness assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be useful:

> **Proposition** (Zariski) (see EGA I, (3.9.8) in Springer edition)
>
> *Let $f: (A,\mathfrak{m})\to (B,\mathfrak{n})$ be a local homomorphism of noetherian local rings. Assume that:*
>
> - *$f$ is injective.*
> - *$\hat{A}$ is a domain.*
> - *$f$ is essentially of finite type.*
>
> *Then the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology on $A$ is induced by the $\mathfrak{n}$-adic topology on $B$.*

Of course this implies that $\hat{f}$ is injective. If we don't assume that $\hat{A}$ is a domain (but $A$ is) it is easy to construct counterexamples.

Comment: Wait, but what about the following example: $A=\mathbb Z[t]_{(p,t)}$ and $B=\mathbb Z[t]_{(t)}$. Clearly $A\subset B$, but $\hat A= \mathbb Z_p[[t]]$ and $\hat B=\mathbb Q[[t]]$

Comment: Moreover I'm looking at EGA I (chapter 0 of Springer edition), and I cannot find any 3.9.8.

Comment: @manifold: your example is not a local homomorphism (the map $A_{\mathfrak p} \to A_{\mathfrak q}$ for $\mathfrak p \supsetneq \mathfrak q$ never is).

Comment: @manifold: it's 3.9.8 of chapter 1 (not chapter 0), on page  255.