# A question on algebraic independence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, power-series

Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n, g \in \mathbb{F}_q[x_1,...,x_m]$. Assume that $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ vanish at $0$, so that $\mathbb{F}_q[[f_1,...,f_n]]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{F}_q[[x_1,...,x_n]]$. Suppose that we have $g \in \mathbb{F}_q[[ f_1,...,f_n ]]$. Does it then follow that $g$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_q(f_1,...,f_n)$?

Comment: What does it mean for an element of $\mathbf F_q[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ to be in $\mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$? While there is an injection $\mathbf F_q[f_1,\ldots,f_n] \to \mathbf F_q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, this does not extend (let alone canonically) to a map $\mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]] \to \mathbf F_q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Comment: @RishabhKothary Sorry, I did not pay attention to that. I suppress my suggestion.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I interpret the question as saying, let $g\in \mathbb{F}_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$. Suppose that $g\in \mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$; does it follow that $g$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_q(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn The example running in my head is $f_1 = x_1 + x_2^2$ and $f_2 = x_2 + x_1^2$, then $x_1 = f_1 + f_2^2 + f_1^4 +.....$ when the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$. Here clearly $x_1$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_2(f_1,f_2)$

Comment: Ok, but in that example the result is true for transcendence degree reasons: they are all contained in the field $\mathbf F_2(x_1,x_2)$ of transcendence degree $2$, and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are algebraically independent. In @TimothyChow's interpretation, you could take $x_1 = f \in \mathbf F_q[[f]]$ and $g = x_2 \in \mathbf F_q[[f]]$ any algebraically independent element. Then $f$ is polynomial in $x_1$ and $x_2$, i.e. contained in the subring $\mathbf F_q[x_1,x_2]$, but $g$ is not algebraic over $\mathbf F_q(f)$.

Comment: @TimothyChow unless I'm misinterpreting your definition. There likewise isn't a *natural* extension of the injection $\mathbf F_q[f_1,\ldots,f_n] \hookrightarrow \mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$ to a map $\mathbf F_q[x_1,\ldots,x_m] \to \mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$, but you could *choose* such an extension (in some cases) by choosing $x_1,\ldots,x_m \in \mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$ such that $f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ is the formal generator $f_i$ of $\mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$.

Comment: @RishabhKothary or are you trying to say that $\mathbf F_q[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$ is a subring of $\mathbf F_q[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$, and all inclusions take place there? You can do that, but only if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ vanish at the origin (otherwise a formal power series in the $f_i$ does not converge in $\mathbf F_q[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$). Please clarify which interpretation of the question you intend.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn you can assume $\mathbb{F}_q[[f_1,...,f_n]]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{F}_q[[x_1,...,x_m]]$ and $f_1,...,f_n$ vanish at origin

Comment: @RishabhKothary I recommend that you edit your question to clarify the issues raised here in the comments. I suspect that the reason some people are voting to close your question is that it is too tersely worded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is true, but it's actually a bit subtle, because the completion $\hat A \to \hat B$ of an injective local homomorphism $A \to B$ of local domains need not be injective.

Given $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ vanishing at the origin, we get a ring homomorphism $k[y_1,\ldots,y_n] \to k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ given by $y_i \mapsto f_i$. There are at least three different things one can mean by $k[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$ in this setting:

- a formal power series ring $k[[y_1,\ldots,y_n]]$ with a map $k[[y_1,\ldots,y_n]] \to k[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$ taking $y_i$ to $f_i$.
- the completion of the image $k[f_1,\ldots,f_n] \subseteq k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ at the origin.
- the image of either one of those in $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$. Because completion preserves surjections, it doesn't matter which of the two we take.

I will use the second as my definition of $k[[f_1,\ldots,f_n]]$, so we'll have to think a little bit about injectivity, but at least it's the completion of the subring $k[f_1,\ldots,f_n] \subseteq k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ that we're trying to understand. Despite these subtleties, we have:

**Lemma.** *Let $k$ be a field, and let $A \hookrightarrow B$ be an injection of domains of finite type over $k$, where $B$ is normal. Let $\mathfrak n \subseteq B$ be a maximal ideal and $\mathfrak m = A \cap \mathfrak n$. Then the dimension of the image of $\hat A_{\mathfrak m} \to \hat B_{\mathfrak n}$ is the dimension of $A$.*

Before giving a proof of the lemma, let's see how it implies the result you're after:

**Corollary.** *Let $k$ be a field, and let $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ be elements vanishing at the origin. If $g \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ is in the image of $k[[y_1,\ldots,y_n]] \to k[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$ given by $y_i \mapsto f_i$, then $g$ is algebraic over the subfield $k(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ of $k(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$.*

*Proof.* We may replace $g$ by $g-c$ for some $c \in k$ to assume $g$ vanishes at the origin as well. Write $A = k[f_1,\ldots,f_n]$, $B = k[f_1,\ldots,f_n,g]$, and $C = k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$, and note that $C$ is normal (even smooth). The hypotheses imply that the images of $\hat A \to \hat C$ and $\hat B \to \hat C$ agree, so the lemma above shows that $\dim A = \dim B$. But $\dim A = \operatorname{trdeg}(k(f_1,\ldots,f_n)/k)$, and likewise for $B$ [Tag [00P0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00P0)], so these coincide if and only if $k(f_1,\ldots,f_n) \to k(f_1,\ldots,f_n,g)$ is algebraic [Tag [030H](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030H)]. $\square$

The following example shows the subtleties with completion and injections:

**Example.** Let $A = k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3-x^2)$ be the affine coordinate ring of a nodal cubic (let's say $\operatorname{char} k \neq 2,3$), and let $B = k[t]$ be its normalisation via the map
\begin{align*}
k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2) &\to k[t] & &\\
x &\mapsto t^2+2t & &(= (t+1)^2-1),\\
y &\mapsto t^3+3t^2+2t & &(= (t+1)^3-(t+1)).
\end{align*}
Then the local homomorphism $A_{(x,y)} \to B_{(t)}$ is injective, but after completion it becomes isomorphic to
\begin{align*}
k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2) &\to k[[t]]\\
x, y &\mapsto 2t,
\end{align*}
which has kernel generated by $x-y$ (this is (partially) explained in Hartshorne, Chapter I, Example 5.6.3). Geometrically, this corresponds to the fact that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has two branches $y = \pm x$ meeting at the origin, whereas $\operatorname{Spec} B$ only picks out the one corresponding to $y = x$ (indeed, $t+1 = y/x$, and we're zooming in around $t=0$).

The proof of the lemma above is 'standard' but tedious.

*Proof of Lemma.* This would be easy if $\hat A \to \hat B$ were injective, since $\dim \hat A = \dim A$ [Tag [07NV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NV)]. As in the case of the nodal curve above, we'll see that in general the map on completions $\hat A \to \hat B$ picks out certain local branches through $\mathfrak m$, which all have the same dimension.

By [Tag [0CB4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CB4)(1)], there exists an étale $A$-algebra $A'$ and a prime $\mathfrak m' \subseteq A'$ above $\mathfrak m$ with $A/\mathfrak m \stackrel\sim\to A'/\mathfrak m'$ such that the number of local branches through $\mathfrak m$ is equal to the number of irreducible components of $A'$ through $\mathfrak m'$. Now $A'$ is no longer a domain, but it is still reduced [Tag [033B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033B)] and equidimensional. Let $B'$ be the tensor product $A' \otimes_A B$, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak n'$ corresponding to the surjection $B' \to A'/\mathfrak m' \otimes_{A/\mathfrak m} B/\mathfrak n$, which is just $B/\mathfrak n$ since $A/\mathfrak m \stackrel\sim\to A'/\mathfrak m'$ is an isomorphism. Then $B'$ is normal [Tag [033C](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033C)], hence a product of normal domains [Tag [030C](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030C)], so we replace $B'$ by the factor containing the prime $\mathfrak n'$ and assume $B'$ is a domain.

The maps $A \to A'$ and $B \to B'$ are étale and induce isomorphisms on residue fields, so they also induce isomorphisms on completions (this follows from [Tag [06LJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LJ)(b)], but should be easier). We have $\dim A = \dim A'$ and $\dim B = \dim B'$ [Tag [00ON](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ON)], but $A'$ need not be a domain, nor $A' \to B'$ injective. The kernel $\mathfrak p$ of $A' \to B'$ is an ideal whose restriction to $A$ is $0$, and since $A \to A'$ is an injective map of equidimensional rings of the same dimension, this forces $\mathfrak p$ to be a minimal prime ideal. Let $A'' = A'/\mathfrak p \subseteq B'$, which by equidimensionality of $A'$ again has dimension $\dim A$.

Thus, we may replace $A \hookrightarrow B$ by $A'' \hookrightarrow B'$. Then all hypotheses of the lemma are still satisfied, and moreover $A$ has only one local branch at $\mathfrak m$. Then the same goes for $\hat A$ [Tag [0C2E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C2E)], so $\hat A$ is unibranch [Tag [0C37](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C37)(2)]. Since it is also reduced [Tag [07N2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NZ)(3)], it is a domain [Tag [0BPZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BPZ)]. By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/302460/82179), this implies that the map $\hat A \to \hat B$ is injective, which is the case we started with. $\square$

**Picture.** In the case of a nodal curve, the étale local picture separating the two branches through the origin is shown in Hartshorne, Chapter III, Exercise 10.6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It might take me a while to parse through the entire proof and clarify my doubts if I have them.